# error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> qualifyForDiscount'|

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void calculateCarpetSize (int length, int width)
{
    float carpetSize = (length * width);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(0);
}

void calculateCarpetPrice (float carpetSize, float sellingPrice )
{
    float carpetPrice = ( carpetSize * sellingPrice );
}

void calculateCarpetCost (float carpetSize, float sellingPrice )
{
    float salesTax = 0.14;
    float carpetCost = (carpetSize * sellingPrice * salesTax);
    cout.precision(2);
}

void calculateLabourCost ( float carpetSize, float labour)
{
    labour = 24.00;
    float labourCost = carpetSize * labour;
}

bool qualifyForDiscount (int customerNumber)
{
    if ( customerNumber < 99999)
    {
        void computeDiscount (float carpetCost);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void computeDiscount (float carpetCost, float discountPercentage)
{
    cout << "Enter the percentage discount ." << endl;
    cin >> discountPercentage;
    float carpetCostDiscount = carpetCost * discountPercentage;
}

void printCustomerStatement( )
{
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "CROSWELL CARPET STORE" << endl;
    cout << "STATEMENT" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int customerName;
    int customerSurname;
    int customerNumber;
    float carpetSize;
    float carpetPrice;
    float sellingPrice;
    float salesTax = 0.14;
    float labourCost;
    int labour = 24.00;
    float length;
    float width;
    float discount;
    float discountPercentage;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(2);

    cout << "Please enter the information" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the customer's first name: " << endl;
    cin >> customerName;
    cout << "\n Enter customers surname: " << endl;
    cin >> customerSurname;
    cout << "\n The length of the room: " << endl;
    cin >> length;
    cout << "\n Enter the width of the room: " << endl;
    cin >> width;
    cout << "\n Enter the carpet selling price: " << endl;
    cin >> sellingPrice;

    int printCustomerStatement;

    {
        cout << "\n Customer name   :    " << endl;
        cin >> customerName >> customerSurname ;
        cout << "Customer number   :    " << endl;
        cin >> customerNumber;
        cout << "\n Carpet price   :    " << endl;
        cin >> carpetPrice;
        cout << "Labour   :    " << endl;
        cin >> labour;
        cout << "\n Subtotal   :    " << endl;
        cin >> carpetPrice;
        cout << "Less Discount   :    " << endl;
        cin >> qualifyForDiscount;
        cout << "\n Subtotal: " <<endl;
        cin >> carpetPrice;
        cout << "Plus tax: " << endl;
        cin >> salesTax;
        cout << "Total: " << endl;
        cin >> carpetPrice;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is an error and I cant figure out how to solve it.

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> qualifyForDiscount'

Please help me out.

Comment: `qualifyForDiscount` is a function.  You cannot input to a function.

Comment: `qualifyForDiscount` is a function. What is `std::cin >> qualifyForDiscount` supposed to do ?

Comment: A tutorial on functions and scopes would go a long way. You're trying to call functions in more than one incorrect way and trying to magically share local variables between functions instead of using return values.

Comment: I would suggest you to start small. Thats way too much code with way too much things that dont make sense. Take for example `void calculateCarpetPrice (float carpetSize, float sellingPrice ){    float carpetPrice = ( carpetSize * sellingPrice );}` ... there is no error, but still that function is not doing what you think it does. Try to make a program with a single function and try to get it right, then add more...

Comment: Open your favourite C++ book and start reading at chapter 1. Don't forget to read the text, don't just look at examples. Do all the exercises, especially those that you want to skip because they are too easy.